# CAPIHook forcibly hooks ::LoadLibrary from QT dll

Tags: c++, qt

I use QT 4.8.6, MSVC 2013. We use API hook to intercept exceptions:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
...
#ifdef _WIN32 
  CAPIHook apiHook("kernel32.dll",  "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter",(PROC)RedirectedSetUnhandledExceptionFilter);
#endif
...
}
```

But, does anybody can explain me why  ::LoadLibrary call from QT redirected to HMODULE WINAPI CAPIHook::LoadLibraryW2(PCWSTR pszModulePath)?

From there:

```
for (int i = 0; i < searchOrder.count(); ++i) {
    QString fullPathAttempt = searchOrder.at(i);
    if (!fullPathAttempt.endsWith(QLatin1Char('\\')))
        fullPathAttempt.append(QLatin1Char('\\'));
    fullPathAttempt.append(fileName);
    HINSTANCE inst = ::LoadLibrary((const wchar_t *)fullPathAttempt.utf16());
    if (inst != 0)
        return inst;
}
```

Where fullPathAttempt is "C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll"

To here:

```
HMODULE WINAPI CAPIHook::LoadLibraryW2(PCWSTR pszModulePath) {
   HMODULE hmod = ::LoadLibraryW(pszModulePath);
   FixupNewlyLoadedModule(hmod, 0);
   return(hmod);
```

}

Full call stack:
[Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqpCI.png)

This is very expensive redirect in some cases. 
How to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please explain your question? You are calling Qt LoadLibrary function and surprised that on Windows it is a wrapper for LoadLibrary of WinAPI?

Comment: Now i understand that there is no any magic. Everything  works as it should works and this is just my mistake.  The problem was in override **paint** method in my derived from qt class. In this method i call **setStyleSheet** which calls ::LoadLibrary in  the end and since **paint** method calls on redrawing widgets we waste a lot of time.